# What comics follow MCU Agent Coulson and Agents of SHIELD?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

I'm new to the sprawling Marvel Multiverse am trying to follow the characters from the television Agents of SHIELD in comics.

What comics follow MCU Agent Coulson and Agents of SHIELD? Where do the fit in on the TV series timeline?

Comment: This isn't a recommendation question, and it's actually a very finitely scoped list as the MCU doesn't have any ongoing comic series, just movie tie-in books.

Comment: @phantom42: So there are no comics at all featuring the TV Agents of SHIELD?

Comment: Not at this time, no.

Comment: @phantom42: Then that's an answer.

Comment: Actually.. wait. checking something. There may be a very new one...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Currently, there are no on-going comic series following the MCU version of the Agents of SHIELD.

There are a few books titled *Agents of SHIELD*, including [a new 2016 book](http://marvel.com/comics/series/20607/agents_of_shield_2016_-_present) which is billed as being "inspired by" the show.

> It's high-stakes espionage in the Marvel Universe in this brand-new series inspired by the hit television show Marvel's Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.

However, while the comics use characters who are on the show, the comics are firmly set within the main Earth-616 (comics only) universe, as it crosses over with the recent Civil War 2 storyline, and involves Tony Stark interacting with a known-to-be-alive Phil Coulson.

As such, if you're trying to follow the further adventures of the characters of the TV show between the episodes in the MCU (Earth-199999), we're currently out of luck.

There are, however, a few one-shot and mini-series MCU tie-in comics that involve Phil Coulson. These all occur *before* the TV show, and do not involve any show related characters other than Coulson and Fury.

- [Iron Man 2: Public Identity](http://marvel.com/comics/issue/32406/iron_man_2_public_identity_2010_1)
- [Iron Man 2: Agents of SHIELD](http://marvel.com/comics/series/12893/iron_man_2_agents_of_shield_2010)
- [Marvel's The Avengers Prelude: Fury's Big Week](http://marvel.com/comics/series/15365/marvels_the_avengers_prelude_furys_big_week_2011_-_2012)

Comment: So it seems like (from [the link](http://marvel.com/comics/series/20607/agents_of_shield_2016_-_present)) the answer is yes: there are 9 (so far) linked to the TV characters. Right?

Comment: There are currently nine issues of a book using characters that have alt-versions in the MCU. The 2016 book is 100% Earth-616 (non-MCU). Daisy Johnson of the 2016 book is not the same as the Daisy Johnson of the TV show.

Comment: I'm just confused because the same link is used to say no (above) and yes ([here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/134736/2264)). Could you break out which things on the linked page are which?

Comment: Frankly, the other answer is wrong. The comic we've both linked exists 100% in Earth-616. Many of the characters on the show were existing characters in the comics. The writers assembled those characters and created some Earth-616 versions of the new characters from the TV show and put them into the Earth-616 book. Beyond matched names and inspirations, the 2016 book has NOTHING to do with the TV show.

Comment: Cool. And could you give a direct link to the 1-9 book that uses (alt-versions) of the MCU characters (just for clarity)? Thx.

Comment: The 2016 book crosses over with non-MCU characters and events. All of the events with Hive and Daisy and Luke, and Raina, and Coulson losing his hand - those don't cross over into the 2016 book as that all happens in Earth-199999 (the MCU) - completely separate.

Comment: Not sure what you're looking for exactly. The link I posted is for Marvel's page for the series. That's the one that uses the Earth-616 versions. There are currently no comics that use the Earth-199999 MCU versions. You can read that book to follow adventures of Phil and Daisy and Deathlok, but it's not the same ones on TV.

Comment: So in "There are currently nine issues of a book using characters that have alt-versions in the MCU. The 2016 book is 100% Earth-616 (non-MCU)", the "2016 book" and "a book" are the same thing?

Comment: Hop into [agents of nothing](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19346/agents-of-nothing) where we can maybe explain this better

Answer (score 4):

**Agents of SHIELD 2016**

There is an ongoing current series, Agents of SHIELD. It features many of the same characters in the show, as different versions of themselves, with similarities to the show. It bills itself as "Inspired by the hit TV series".

**This series exists in the main, current Marvel comic universe, but it is NOT part of the Marvel Cinematic Universe. The names and  personalities are similar, but it is taking some characters/concepts from the TV show, and porting hem into the comic universe.**

The 7th issue was just released in mid-July as a Civil War 2 tie-in issue.

The series has featured, so far, Coulson, Skye, Melinda May, Fitz/Simmons, Ward, Bobbie Morse (Mockingbird), and Deathlock. There may be others too. It also features many other Marvel heroes/characters as well.

Link to series on Marvel's website:

http://marvel.com/comics/series/20607/agents_of_shield_2016_-_present

**SHIELD 2014**

There was a 12-issue run of SHIELD in the pre-Secret Wars Marvel Comic Universe that also featured many of the same characters as in the 2016 series, using the same premise. Similar characters from the TV show, different universe than the MCU.

http://marvel.com/comics/issue/51113/shield_2014_1

Comment: According to this [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/134737/2264) answers wrong. Could you clarify?

Comment: Not sure how to clarify. There's an ongoing series that uses characters of the same names, similar personalities, different positions/situations, and different marvel universe (this comic is in the comic universe)

Comment: these two answers are saying the same thing. There are no comics that follow the MCU characters. There are comics *inspired by* the MCU characters but they are not the same.

Comment: Not sure how to handle multiple answers. When I started typing my answer, there were no other answers.

Comment: Just added text in bold to hopefully clear up confusion. The comic series I linked is NOT part of the Marvel MCU, but is part of the current Marvel comic universe, the one currently in Civil War 2.

Comment: @KutuluMike: One reason that I didn't "get" that these answers are "saying the same thing" is that the first starts "with there is no on-going series" and the second starts with "there is an ongoing current series" — plus (from the first answerer): "Frankly, the other answer is wrong."

Comment: @Joe multiple answers are common. Just write yours as best you can write it and don't worry about any others. People can (and usually do) upvote more than one answer.

Comment: Actually, I hadn't even read this answer. I was just going based off of OP's assessment that he related in the comments. I apologize.

Comment: Forgot about the 2014 SHIELD series. Edited my answer to reflect.

Comment: There's also *BATTLE SCARS*, the post *FEAR ITSELF* mini-series that gave us Nick Fury Jr. (the MCU/Ultimate Universe version of Fury), and "Phil Coulson". Both characters also had prominent roles in *SECRET AVENGERS* v. 3 (2014-2015)